# Two differents Iterator in a same Java class

Tags: java, iterator

I'm asking maybe for a strange (maybe really useless) question, but i'm stuck on this problem since a while. I'm not ok with Iterators, please don't blame me :D

I have a java class named MondeIG

```java
public class MondeIG extends SujetObserve implements Iterable<EtapeIG>{

private HashMap<String, EtapeIG> etapesIG;
private ArrayList<ArcIG> arcSelectionnees;
//and other

public MondeIG() {
super();
this.etapesIG = new HashMap<String, EtapeIG>();
this.arcSelectionnees = new ArrayList<ArcIG>();
}

@Override
    public Iterator<EtapeIG> iterator() {
        return this.etapesIG.values().iterator();
    }

    public Iterator<ArcIG> iteratorArc(){
        return this.arcSelectionnees.iterator();
    }

//In the same class I would like to iterate on these both structures :

public void f1(){
Iterator<EtapeIG> it = this.activiteSelectionnees.iterator();
//no problem
}

public void f2(){
Iterator<ArcIG> it = this.arcSelectionnees.iteratorArc();
//PROBLEM -> Cannot resolve method 'iteratorArc' in 'ArrayList'
}
```

I don't understand why, do you have ideas ?

Comment: Your variable `arcSelectionnees` is of type `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` does not provide a method called `iteratorArc`.You can call `this.iteratorArc()` if that's what you want...?

Comment: Why do you call that method on `this.arcSelectionnees` when you call `iteratorArc`, a method of the class you're currently in?

Comment: Look into the `Visitor` design pattern. Alternatively, you could allow streaming over your structure in a way that the user can map between the different variables of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be

```
    Iterator<ArcIG> it = this.arcSelectionnees.iterator();
```

or

```
    Iterator<ArcIG> it = this.iteratorArc();
```